# Chrome Extension Popup Opened Event

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to trigger a refresh of the content on my popup when it is opened. According to the [chrome.browserAction docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked) `chrome.browserAction.onClicked will not fire if the browser action has a popup.`

If I refresh the popup content on document ready, it is only refreshed once when the browser is opened (instead of every time the popup is "shown").

Is there an event fired when the user clicks the browser button/the popup is shown?

I really don't want to have to do a `setTimeout(refreshContent(), 1000)` on document ready...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Odd.

I have the following manifest:

```
{
  "name": "A test",
  "version": "1.1",
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "browser_action": {
      "name": "TEts",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I have the following popup.html

```
<p>Hello</p>
<script src="popup.js">
</script>
```

popup.js

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("onload" + Date())
}
```

And every time that I go into to inspect the logs via Chrome Dev tools I only see one entry and it is the updated "onload" log with the most recent time which suggests that the page is getting reloaded.